# Lock and refresh implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, locking

I have a key to task mapping and I need to run the task only if the task for the given is not already running. Pseudo code follows. I believe there is lot of scope for improvement. I'm locking on the map and hence almost serializing access to CacheFreshener. Is there a better way of doing this? We know that when I'm trying to lock a key k1, there is no point in cache freshener call for key k2 waiting for lock.

```
class CacheFreshener
{
     private ConcurrentDictionary<string,bool> lockMap;

     public RefreshData(string key, Func<string, bool> cacheMissAction)
     {
         lock(lockMap)
         {
             if (lockMap.ContainsKey(key))
             {
                 // no-op
                 return;
             }
             else
             {
                lockMap.Add(key, true); 
             }  
         }

         // if you are here means task is not already present
         cacheMissAction(key);

         lock(lockMap) // Do we need to lock here??
         {
             lockMap.Remove(key);
         }  
     }  

}
```

Comment: Questions of type `Is there a better way of doing this?` usually go to the CodeReview SE.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Perhaps you are right, however **pseudo-code** is **ALWAYS** off topic on [codereview.se].

Comment: @nhgrif Although he called it pseudo-code, it is simply C#. I believe he was thinking more towards the direction of "unpolished code" or "work in progress" - not really a code in pseudo language. Either way, it's just C#.

Comment: @YoryeNathan These are also off-topic at [codereview.se].  Code Review questions *must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete example.*  Please read [the Code Review help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) before making more recommendations.

Comment: @nhgrif But this IS a concrete example. He misused the words pseudo-code. I'm sorry, does this not compile for you?

Comment: The fact that this compiles doesn't automatically make it on-topic for [codereview.se].  Please visit [the Code Review help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) or [meta.codereview.se], or [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if you have any other questions about the scope of [codereview.se].

Comment: @YoryeNathan Also, no.  This doesn't compile.  There's no return type for `RefreshData`.

Comment: @nhgrif You're right, I missed that. One `void` and it's C#. Whether the C# version of this is or isn't off-topic in CR, I do not know. I merely suggested a more appropriate SE site.

Comment: I know you don't know.  That's why I told you--it's not on topic at [codereview.se].

Comment: You're using `ConcurrentDictionary`. Why bother with the `lock` also? Access to the dictionary is already thread-safe. There's even a `TryAdd()` method to accomplish your logic; just return without doing anything if the method returns `false`. As far as whether this could be improved or not, there's not enough context to be able to answer that question. You would need to include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your scenario to get a good answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho..I might be wrong, but, as I understand Concurrent data structures only ensure that their internal state remains un-corrupted in case of multi thread access, but they don't guarantee any exclusive access. In the example above, if I don't lock, two threads might see that the concurrent dictionary doesn't have value and try to refresh. Please correct me if I'm wrong. But, as you suggested, if I use TryAdd, I think my problem is solved without locking.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. Only one thread will be allowed to add the key, so if you use `TryAdd()`, there's no need for additional locking. I agree that if you do the two-step check, you need to `lock`. But `ConcurrentDictionary` includes features obviating that need.

Comment: @PeterDuniho.. do you mind adding this as answer, so that I can accept? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here is an elaborated explanation of what I was getting at relative to my comments…

The basic issue here seems to be the question of concurrency, i.e. two or more threads accessing the same object at a time. This is the scenario `ConcurrentDictionary` is designed for. If you use the `IDictionary` methods of `ContainsKey()` and `Add()` separately, then you would need explicit synchronization (but only for that operation…in this particular scenario it wouldn't strictly be needed when calling `Remove()`) to ensure these are performed as a single atomic operation. But the `ConcurrentDictionary` class anticipates this need, and includes the `TryAdd()` method to accomplish the same, without the explicit synchronization.

**<aside>**
It is not entirely clear to me the intent behind the code example as given. The code appears to be meant to only store an object in the "cache" for the duration of the invocation of the `cacheMissAction` delegate. The key is removed immediately after. So it does seem like it's not really caching anything per se. It just prevents more than one thread from being in the process of invoking `cacheMissAction` at a time (subsequent threads will fail to invoke it, but also cannot count on it having completed by the time their call to the `RefreshData()` method has completed).
**</aside>**

But taking the code example as given, it's clear that no explicit locking is actually required. The `ConcurrentDictionary` class already provides thread-safe access (i.e. non-corruption of the data structure when used concurrently from multiple threads), and it provides the `TryAdd()` method as a mechanism for adding a key (and its value, though here that's just always a `bool` literal of `true`) to the dictionary that will ensure that only one thread ever has a key in the dictionary at a time.

So we can rewrite the code to look like this instead and accomplish the same goal:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string,bool> lockMap;

public RefreshData(string key, Func<string, bool> cacheMissAction)
{
    if (!lockMap.TryAdd(key, true))
    {
        return;
    }

    // if you are here means task was not already present
    cacheMissAction(key);

    lockMap.Remove(key);
}
```

No `lock` statement is needed for either the add or remove, as the `TryAdd()` handles the entire "check for key and add if not present" operation atomically.

I will note that using a dictionary to do the job of a set could be considered inefficient. If the collection is likely not to be large, it's no big deal, but I do find it odd that Microsoft chose to make the same mistake they made originally when in the pre-generics days you had to use the non-generic dictionary object `Hashtable` to store a set, before `HashSet<T>` came along. Now we have all these easy-to-use classes in `System.Collections.Concurrent`, but no thread-safe implementation of `ISet<T>` in there. Sigh…

That said, if you *do* prefer a somewhat more efficient approach in terms of storage (this is not necessarily a *faster* implementation, depending on the concurrent access patterns of the object), something like this would work as an alternative:

```
private HashSet<string> lockSet;
private readonly object _lock = new object();

public RefreshData(string key, Func<string, bool> cacheMissAction)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        if (!lockSet.Add(key))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    // if you are here means task was not already present
    cacheMissAction(key);

    lock (_lock)
    {
        lockSet.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

In this case, you do need the `lock` statement, because the `HashSet<T>` class is not inherently thread-safe. This is of course very similar to your original implementation, just using the more set-like semantics of `HashSet<T>` instead.

Comment: Great answer Peter! :)